# issues in magento configurable product feed for google merchant

Tags: magento, configurable-product, google-feed-api

I am working on the google merchant feed for configurable products. I am new in this and so far the situation is

> All the products are configurable which are visible on front-end
>
> All simple products are set to not viewed individually as they are
>   linked with some configurable product

the fields in the google feed is

```
id  title   description google product category product type    link    image link  condition   availability    price   sale price  sale price effective date   item group id   age group   color   size    shipping    shipping weight identifier_exists
```

i have successfully get all the data for simple products and use the parent product url for its link field as it is set to not viewed individually

But the problem is now i have to make a feed for configurable product
but

> the price for configurable product is 0
>   the weight is not there

can anyone please share some sample configurable product feed for google merchant

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this will work google or not. The short cut is "uploading the prices for configurable product" , you can upload the least price of associated product to the configurable product.

also , once you upload the configurable product, using "update attributes" , put weight as "1" for all configurable products.

Comment: thanks for reply  nut i cant edit any products like this

Comment: fine, you are right. i hope you using any extension for this google shoppng feed generation ?

Comment: actually in your way i can assign values in my feed csv  on the run also without editing the products in magento.  But i need a sample csv which will create a configurable product in google shopping

Comment: Are you guys manually filling csv and generating feeds ? is there any automatic way ?

Comment: no i am not doing manulayy i am writing dynamically by getting product data ,i am looking for a sample feed csv which will work in google merchant for configurable products in magento

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106540/discussion-between-rohit-goel-and-profile-101).

Comment: did you found solution ?